# Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle - Only Allow Users to Edit Data That They Own

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Symphony Version 2.2 (yah, I know).
FOSRestBundle: 1.5.3

#### Current Scenario

I have a REST Api driving an angular page.  Let's say that each user has a token associated w/ their user record.  Consider the following Urls.

- GET /api/user/{token}/messages
- POST /api/user/{token}/messages
- GET /api/messages/{messageId}
- GET /api/user/{token}/votes
- POST /api/user/{token}/votes

So the user can GET and POST messages.  The user can make votes and see them.

(I have about 30 diff routes like this - the URLs are all over the place).

#### Question

How can I verify that the user is allowed to GET/POST data for the token they're providing?

I do realize I could copy/paste some code to check the given user vs the user from the URL.  Or I could write a service w/ a `checkUser()` function on each endpoint.

My hope, though, is that there is some way of doing this that doesn't require me to check the user on each endpoint's entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Don't send the authentication in the Endpoint.  An endpoint typically should be Idempotent, and should individually identify a particular resource.

Send your authentication tokens in HTTP headers.

With that said, as a strategy, baking in your security using @wonde is a good idea.  I have implemented a custom base controller class in the past, but the filter and event handling built into symphony provides an even sexier solution.

Answer (score 0):

i would create `a before filter` and add the `checkUser()` hook in there , that way you don't have to check the user permission on each endpoint

[example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)